# Usando Apollo Client 3 con React navigation 5 no se reflejan los cambios en los screen si no se recarga la app

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-navigation, stack, screen

Tengo configurado mi apollo client para que inserte automáticamente el token en el header de las peticiones. Funciona correctamente, por ejemplo al obtener el usuario actual, cuyos valores serán mostrados luego del login en el screen resultante "Dashboard". Pero los cambios no se muestran hasta que manualmente recargo la app. Igual sucede al hacer logout que borra el token del localstore y hace un client.resetStore() para borrar la cache de apollo client y pasa al screen home. Siguen apareciendo los datos anteriores hasta que recargo manualmente la página y es entonces que desaparecen.

La configuración del cliente es la siguiente (en App.tsx):

```
 const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    link: ApolloLink.from([logoutLink, authLink, httpLink]),
    // Luego agregué estas opciones pero tampoco funcionó:
    defaultOptions,
  });

const defaultOptions = {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      errorPolicy: 'ignore',
    },
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      errorPolicy: 'all',
    },
  };
```

También probé en mi componente CurrentUser.tsx otras opciones

```
const getCurrentUser = () => {
   const { data } = useQuery(CURRENT_USER, { fetchPolicy: 'network-only', pollInterval: 500 });
    ...
```

Todo parece indicar que el problema está en mi navegación (App.tsx):

```
    return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={token.length > 0 ? 'Dashboard' : 'Home'}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} /> 
...
```

Al parecer se necesita algo como que al pasar de screen se haga un refetch al cliente de apollo.

¿Por favor alguien ha tenido este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucioné el problema. Solo me aseguré de que el token que se le asigna al header del cliente de Apollo se terminara de obtener con async await y al hacer logout limpiar la cache de apollo.

En Client.tsx

```
...
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await getToken();
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    },
  };
});
...
```

En Logout.tsx

```
...
const Logout = () => {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <Button
      mode="outlined"
      onPress={() => {
        // client.resetStore(); // limpia cache y recarga los datos
        client.clearStore(); // limpia cache por completo
        deleteToken(); //borra el token del SecureStore
        saveIsLoggedIn(false); //actualiza variable de cache
        navigation.navigate('Home');
      }}
    >
      Salir
    </Button>
  );
};
...
```